# jQuery can't apply onmousedown to anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, onmousedown

I have a navigation menu like this

```
<ul id="nav">
<li> <a id="firstLink" href="#"> Link 1 </a> </li>
<li> <a id="secondLink" href="#"> Link 2 </a> </li>
<li> <a id="thirdLink" href="#"> Link 3 </a> </li>
<li> <a id="fourthLink" href="#"> Link 4 </a> </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to associate a function to each anchor tag as the mouse is down so I have an external js file and my code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#firstLink').onmousedown(doSomething());
[ ... ]
});

function doSomething() {
// this function does something
}
```

My problem is if I put the event handler inline, the script works and no issue is brought up.

```
<li> <a href="#" id="firstLink" onmousedown="doSomething()"> Link 1 </a> </li>
```

On the other hand if I use the external file, as shown above, nothing happens and Chrome gives me back `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method onmousedown`, Firefox and Firebug return me `$("#firstLink").onmousedown is not a function`. I don't understand, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('#firstLink').onmousedown(doSomething());
```

should be

```
$('#firstLink').mousedown(doSomething);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was getting crazy!! What if `doSomething()` accepts parameters? Is it allowed to pass them while calling the function or do I need to write down:

`$('#firstLink').mousedown(function() {
doSomething(par1, par2);
});`

Comment: @haunted85, you need to write it down link your example.

Answer (score 1):

It is mousedown and not onmousedown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#firstLink').mousedown(doSomething());
[ ... ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can prevent the default event by doing something like this:

```
$('#firstLink').onmousedown(function(e){

e.preventDefault();


// do something

});
```

Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

But you might want to condier using ´.click()´ instead of mousedown.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the "on" event handler. As of Jquery 1.7, this is the proper way to attach
an Event - it replaces bind(), delegate() and live().

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#firstLink').on("mousedown", doSomething());
});
```